# Crontab using incorrect version of Python to run script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

crontab is using version 2.6 to run a script that requires 2.7 to run. How do I set the default version of Python to be 2.7 permanently?
running ./file.py works fine, its just when its run through crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
*,30 *  *  *  * root /root/file.py >>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1
```

edit
issue resolved

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/python
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
*,30 *  *  *  * root /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /root/file.py >>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: does your enviornment has python 2.7 installed ?

Comment: yes I can run ./file.py fine just when its run through crontab its an issue

Comment: where is python2.7 installed?

Comment: ok in your shell type which python and use the path and add it as the first path in your PATH variable

Comment: im not sure where python 2.7 is installed but in /usr/bin i have "python", "python2" and "python 2.6"

Comment: Try `which python` and `which python2.7` on the command line.

Comment: it will more than likely be in /usr/local somewhere

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python2.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a separate version of python installed for 2.7 you can look for it with `whereis python`

I have CentOS 6 which comes with 2.6 by default, so this command returns:

```
python2: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6
```

Of these `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` is the one I'm interested in, so when I put a job in crontab, I choose it explicitly:

```
30 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/mike/job.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Update the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) of your Python script to use Python 2.7 explicitly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

This first line tells Unix which interpreter to use.